# Does Spark SQL v3.3 supports offset as an expression in lead() window function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the above query in spark 3.3 wherein it's throwing the following error in lead function

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'lead(y.dense_rnk1, ((y.last_val1 - y.first_val1) + 1), NULL)' due to data type mismatch: Offset expression '((last_val1#18047 - first_val1#18046) + 1)' must be a literal.

According to Spark SQL documentation, v2.3 itself allows offset to be given in the form of an expression.
Whereas here I am using v3.3 and still it's throwing this error.

```
    SELECT
      y.*,
      LEAD(y.dense_rnk1, (y.last_val1 - y.first_val1 + 1), NULL) OVER (
        PARTITION BY y.Shipment_Tracking_Nr,
        y.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
        ORDER BY
          y.Reporting_Dt
      ) AS lead_dense_rnk1
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          x.*,
          FIRST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER(
            PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr,
            x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id,
            x.dense_rnk1
            ORDER BY
              x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
              AND CURRENT ROW
          ) AS first_val1,
          LAST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER(
            PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr,
            x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id,
            x.dense_rnk1
            ORDER BY
              x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
              AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
          ) AS last_val1
```

1. Tried casting last_va1 and first_val1 to integer

```
LEAD(y.dense_rnk1, (CAST(y.last_val1 AS INT) - CAST(y.first_val1 AS INT) + 1), NULL) 
OVER (
        PARTITION BY y.Shipment_Tracking_Nr,
        y.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
        ORDER BY
          y.Reporting_Dt
      ) AS lead_dense_rnk1
```

2. Although NULL values won't be populated for these columns (i.e. last_val1 and first_val1), I tried using
   COALESCE function *(FYI -COALESCE function returns the first non NULL value)*

```
LEAD(y.dense_rnk1, (CAST(COALESCE(y.last_val1,0) AS INT) - CAST(COALESCE(y.first_val1,0) AS INT) + 1), NULL) OVER (
        PARTITION BY y.Shipment_Tracking_Nr,
        y.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
        ORDER BY
          y.Reporting_Dt
      ) AS lead_dense_rnk1
```

Comment: it seems to be saying that you must use a constant expression for LAG/LEAD second parameter

Comment: Spark is not SQL Server - please correct your tags

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using a CTE, or derived table, so that that columns are available for your use of lead without them being a direct calculation. e.g.

```
WITH y
AS (
    SELECT
          x.*
        , FIRST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr
            , x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
            , x.dense_rnk1 ORDER BY x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) AS first_val1
        , LAST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr
            , x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
            , x.dense_rnk1 ORDER BY x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) AS last_val1
        , (
            LAST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr
                , x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
                , x.dense_rnk1 ORDER BY x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                ) - FIRST_VALUE(x.row_num1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY x.Shipment_Tracking_Nr
                , x.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id
                , x.dense_rnk1 ORDER BY x.row_num1 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                ) + 1
            ) AS lead_offset
    FROM x
    )
SELECT
      y.*
    , LEAD(y.dense_rnk1, y.lead_offset, NULL) OVER (
        PARTITION BY y.Shipment_Tracking_Nr
        , y.Tracking_Item_Unique_Id ORDER BY y.Reporting_Dt
        ) AS lead_dense_rnk1
FROM y;
```

nb: as I don't use Spark I'm not 100% on the support of offset, but [this says it is supported](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lead.html):